# How can I split a line and assign index number for a graph's links connection in java?

Tags: java, json

I need help to generate a graph's link connection in json format which are index numbers. I can manage to generate the 1st part of nodes index numbers but can't do the 2nd part of links index numbers. Nodes index number should be plotted links index no. Anyone please help.

**Input file:**

> Abdelaziz Bouteflika,Bush,1
>
> Albert II of Belgium,Bush,1
>
> Albert Wehrer,Bush,1
>
> Berlusconi,Bush,1
>
> Bernard-Montgomery,Bush,1
>
> Bush,Fidel-Castro,1
>
> Bernard-Montgomery,Albert Wehrer,5

**Expected Output file:**

```
{

  "nodes":[

    {"name":"Bush","Id":0},
    {"name":"Abdelaziz Bouteflika","Id":1},
    {"name":"Albert II of Belgium","Id":2},
    {"name":"Albert Wehrer","Id":3},
    {"name":"Berlusconi","Id":4},
    {"name":"Bernard-Montgomery","Id":5},
    {"name":"Fidel-Castro","Id":6}
     ],
  "links":[

    {"source":1,"target":0},
    {"source":2,"target":0},
    {"source":3,"target":0},
    {"source":4,"target":0},
    {"source":5,"target":0},
    {"source":6,"target":0},
    {"source":5,"target":3}
  ]

}
```

**My code:**

```
public class Link_Of_Index {

    List<String> linklist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void getIndexNo() throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:/Workspace/Entity_Graph_Creation/WebContent/Graph_nodes_1.csv"));
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("E:/workspace/Entity_Graph_Creation/Input/links.json"));
        try{
            String line = null;
            int index=0;
            while (( line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] splits = line.split(",");
                linklist1.add(splits[0]);
                linklist1.add(splits[1]);
                linklist1.add(splits[2]);
            }
            for (String s: linklist1) {
                if (!finalList.contains(s)) {
                    finalList.add(s);
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                    obj.put("Id", index);
                    obj.put("name", s);
                    fw.write(obj.toString()+ ","+ "\n");
                    index ++;   
                }
                fw.flush();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Link_Of_Index inx = new Link_Of_Index();
        inx.getIndexNo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which meaning has "1" on the line "Abdelaziz Bouteflika,Bush,1", and what means "5" in "Bernard-Montgomery,Albert Wehrer,5" ? Is this the weight of the link?

Comment: You should have included this requirement earlier. However, this makes no sense for the following reason: the event Attribute gives additional information about a link (when did 2 persons meet?). This does not affect or change the nodes directly. Instead, the "links" in the JSON Output will receive this event data.

Comment: yes, but by clicking every node it should display the associated events, that's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I rewrote the entire answer to reflect your new requirements. For the next time, you should mention that in first place, or make 2 seperate questions of it.

```
public class GraphFileIO {

    private static final Comparator<Node> NODE_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Node>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Node node1, Node node2) {
            return node1.compareTo(node2);
        }
    };

    private Map<Node, List<Edge>> graph;
    private final File sourceFile;

    public GraphFileIO(final File pSource) throws IOException {
        if (pSource.exists()) {
            sourceFile = pSource;
        } else {
            throw new IOException();
        }
    }

    public void readGraph() throws IOException {
        int index = 1;
        graph = new TreeMap<>(NODE_COMPARATOR);

        for (String line : Files.readAllLines(sourceFile.toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset())) {
            if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                continue; // skip blank lines
            }
            // csv columns:
            // node 1, node 2, weight, event
            String[] splits = line.split(",");

            Node n = new Node(index, splits[0]);

            if (!graph.containsKey(n)) {
                graph.put(n, new ArrayList<Edge>());
            }

            n = new Node(index, splits[0]);

            if (!graph.containsKey(n)) {
                graph.put(n, new ArrayList<Edge>());
            }

            Edge edge = new Edge(splits[3]);
            for (Entry<Node, List<Edge>> entry : graph.entrySet()) {

                Node node = entry.getKey();

                if (node.getName().equals(splits[0])) {
                    edge.setSource(node.getId());

                    entry.getValue().add(edge);
                } else if (node.getName().equals(splits[1])) {
                    edge.setTarget(node.getId());

                    // if edges are bi-directional, uncomment the next line of
                    // code

                    /* entry.getValue().add(edge); */
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void writeGraphToFile(final File targetFile) throws IOException {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        JSONArray nodeList = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray edgeList = new JSONArray();

        for (Entry<Node, List<Edge>> entry : graph.entrySet()) {
            JSONObject jsonNode = new JSONObject();
            jsonNode.put("name", entry.getKey().getName());
            jsonNode.put("Id", entry.getKey().getId());
            jsonNode.put("event", entry.getValue());
            nodeList.add(jsonNode);

            for (Edge link : entry.getValue()) {
                JSONObject link = new JSONObject();
                link.put("source", link.getSourceID());
                link.put("target", link.getTargetID());

                edgeList.add(link);
            }
        }
        obj.put("nodes", nodeList);
        obj.put("links", edgeList);

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(targetFile);
        fw.write(obj.toJSONString());
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        File source = new File("C:\\Sandbox\\src\\foo\\test.csv");
        File target = new File("C:\\Sandbox\\src\\foo\\testresult.csv");

        GraphFileIO g;
        try {
            g = new GraphFileIO(source);
            g.readGraph();
            g.writeGraphToFile(target);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

    private final Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private final String name;
    private final Collection<String> events;

    public Node(Integer id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.events = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    public Collection<String> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Node other = (Node) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node o) {
        return id.compareTo(o.id);
    }

}

public class Edge {

    private final String event;
    private Integer sourceID;
    private Integer targetID;

    public Edge(String string) {
        event = string;
    }

    public void setSource(Integer id) {
        sourceID = id;
    }

    public void setTarget(Integer id) {
        targetID = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return event;
    }

    public Integer getSourceID() {
        return sourceID;
    }

    public Integer getTargetID() {
        return targetID;
    }

    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }
}
```

Comment: obj.add(list); it says undefined. Yes those are the weight of the links.

Comment: Hello, it could be list.add(obj); but then it does not print anything. Please help. I'm using import.org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import.org.json.simple.JSONObject; as libraries.

Comment: I have another query. if the input file: Abdelaziz Bouteflika,Bush,1,Bush meet with Abdelaziz in 1998, How can I add it with nodes, like: {"name":"Bush","Id":0,"event":"Bush meet with Abdelaziz in 1998"}. But nodes and edges should be sorted with it's id.

Comment: Your comment is confusing. A) The example  "{"name":"Bush","Id":0,"event":"Bush meet with Abdelaziz in 1998"}" doesn't describe a node, but an edge. B) Since nodes have IDs, they can be sorted easily, but how do you want the edges to be sorted? Please clarify.

Comment: sorry the nodes should be sorted out with it's Id no.